# How to prove that $\gcd((a^m -1)/(a-1),a-1)=\gcd((a-1),m)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I have this identity
$$
\gcd\left({a^m -1\over a-1},a-1\right)=\gcd(a-1,m) 
$$ where

- $m$ is positive integer and
- $a>1$.

How can I prove it?

I tried to do so by expanding the expression $(a^m - 1 )/ (a-1)$ and then use the Euclidean algorithm or use the $\gcd$ properties, but still I wasn't able to prove it.

Comment: Hint: Substitute a=b+1 and expand. The division is then much easier.